# How do you open a new JPanel after some time passes (Java)?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have three classes I am working with. The first one (JFrame) calls the Splash class (JPanel). After a certain amount of time, I want the panel to be removed and replaced with another panel in the Menu class.

My main class currently looks like this (the init method is called by the main method in the same class)...

```
public void init() throws InterruptedException{
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Menu menu = new Menu(this);
        Splash splash = new Splash(this);

        this.getContentPane().add(splash, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        validate();

        setVisible(true);

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        this.removeAll();

        invalidate();
        this.getContentPane().add(menu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        revalidate();

        setVisible(true);

    }
```

The Splash class looks like so...

```
public Splash(Survive survive) throws InterruptedException{
        Color c1 = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        this.setBackground(c1);

        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel();
        jl1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("res/splash.png"));
        this.add(jl1);

    }
```

And the Menu class follows as so...

```
public Menu(Survive survive){
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("res/title.png");

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        Color c1 = new Color(96, 96, 96);
        this.setBackground(c1);

        JButton b0 = new JButton(i1);
        b0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 250));
        b0.setRolloverIcon(i1);
        b0.setOpaque(false);
        b0.setBorderPainted(false);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = -2;
        this.add(b0, gbc);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Singleplayer");
        b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        this.add(b1, gbc);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Options");
        b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        this.add(b2, gbc);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Credits");
        b3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        this.add(b3, gbc);

        JButton b4 = new JButton("Options");
        b4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        this.add(b4, gbc);

    }
```

The purpose of all this is to make a splash screen using swing components. I realize there are easier ways to do this, but I find this method to fit my needs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will keep this in mind the next time I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a one one shot `javax.swing.Timer` to fire the event and a `CardLayout` to hold/swap between the components.